# Handling multiple document version in Mongo Collection

Tags: mongodb

*{Hello. I'm not completely satisfied with the title, Mods please help amend it if necessary}*

We are trying to come up with ways to implement mongoDB on the back end in our project. We have to address a couple of concerns that were raised as below. Some input by experts in the field would be really helpful.

1. Remove / Add entirely new fields into the document given the early development changes --> How best can this be accommodated?

As an example to this, suppose my collection contains about 1000 records, and there is an that contains 'Address' data. owing to operational changes, we need to add to (or replace) the 'Address'  field with an array of 'Street', 'POBOX' etc. and populate them with a certain default value, how best can this be accommodated?

2. Specific scenario wherein not all devices that we run would need to be updated to the latest version. This means that the new "fields" added in the DB would essentially be irrelevant to the devices running the older version of the app. --> How best can this scenario be dealt with?

As an example to this, let us assume that some devices run an earlier version of the app which only looks for 'Address' as a field. Certain devices that are updated to the latest app need will need to refer to the 'Street' and 'POBox' fields instead of the address. How best can this be handled from Mongo's perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in simple words:

As you development will progress, document shape can be changed as necessary.

Depend of change type, structure update can be conducted by one update statement 
or sometimes there will be a need to use aggregation framework and save results in new collection.

For backward compatibility with app version on device in use - document can contain both versions of fields, so older version of application can be used with newer schema.

This could leads to other problem, what to do if document will be updated? That means app could be setup to read from newer schema, but not write (if possible).

If there will be a possibility to use webApi to communicate with app and then with mongo - you can do all migration on the fly, as api will be aware of changes.....

Any comments welcome!

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Would you have any details and references to look at when it comes to documents containing versions etc, web api etc? We're trying to build the app using Meteor, so I'll need to look at it from meteor's perspective as well, to a certain extent.